# How to show DockPanel in MVVM(WPF)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, devexpress

I made MVVM application using DevExpress and WPF. To show data NamesView.xaml View will be called in Document Tab Provided by DevExpress. Code is:

```
void ShowDocument(Int32? key)
{
    if(DocumentManagerService == null)
       return;
    IDocument document = (key != null && key.HasValue) ?
                          GetDocumentById(key.Value) : null;
    if(document == null)
    {
       document = DocumentManagerService.CreateDocument("NamesView", key, this);
    }
    document.Show();
}
```

There is a PanelB in NamesCollectionView.xaml file.How to Show "NamesView.xaml" in Panel(named as PanelB defined in NamesCollectionView.xaml file rather than showing in Document Tab?.  When user will Click on Edit or new button, NamesView file will get open in response.I want that this file to show in PanelB.

**Note:** I f my Question is not clear or if you need some more code to figure it out. Please ask me, i will provide you more detail.

Comment: Isnt it a better idea to post this in DevExpress forums. You will find people dedicated to devexpress there and can help you out easily.

Comment: You could try the: http://avalondock.codeplex.com/